# Proving convexity of a set — a symmetric matrix with a diagonal constraint

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis

I'm trying to formally prove whether the following set is convex or not, but I am not sure on how to go about it.

$$ \left\{ X \in S^2 : X = \begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ y & z  \end{bmatrix}, zx  \geq 0 \right\}
$$

My initial guess is to use quadratic form, and knowing that the Hessian has to be positive-definite I can prove that the set is not convex. The task can be found at the Stanford course on convex optimization.

Comment: What Hessian? You have to take two generic elements of that set and see if any convex combination of them is again an element of that set. It is enough to check at the midpoint, rather than the fully general convex combination.

Comment: I have overthought it and completely misunderstood what I am doing, thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem, hope it helped. If the answer has been useful, please don't forget to upvote and accept, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Take the matrices $A=\begin{pmatrix}3 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & -3\end{pmatrix}$. They both belong to your set,  but ${A+B\over 2}$ doesn't. Thus, the set is not convex.